# Date instead of DateTime?

Tags: vb.net

From what I can tell [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) have the same functionality. Is there a reason why I would want to use one instead of the other?

Comment: I've retagged to VB.NET because VB.NET does have a Date type (actually an alias to DateTime which would explain the question). I hope my assumption is correct.

Comment: @Martinho: Your assumption is correct

Comment: Since its a wash, I'm planning to use DateTime because it makes it more explicit that it contains a time component.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In VB.NET `Date` is an alias to `System.DateTime`, so yes, they're the same thing. You can see all the aliases in [this chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Semantics but the docs do refer to them as _Visual Basic data types_

Comment: and "their supporting common language runtime types". C# says the same thing but includes the word alias. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Comment: So as DateTime is specified in the CLR, this is the better one to use then?

Answer (score 9):

C# has no `Date` type, but `DateTime`s do have a [`Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) which returns a `DateTime` with all of the time-related fields cleared out.

Specifically it returns:

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

VB.NET does have a `Date` type but it is [equivalent to a CLR `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)