# trying to get current date in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I push a button on a web page.
I am trying to get the current date into 3 variables  Year, Month, and Day
In the Code behind I Have:

```
Dim intDay As Integer

intDay = Date.Now.Day
```

I get error message

**Input string was not in a correct format.**

Suggestions?

Comment: DateTime.Now instead of Date???

Comment: @phillip: No, in VB.NET `Date` and `DateTime` both refer to the `System.DateTime` class. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5625852/284240

Comment: That's not the code that causes problems for you. intDay is integer, Day returns integer. There are no string references in your code. Post full code.

Comment: I assume you are trying to convert a string to `Date` somewhere. Show that code and tell us what value the string has and what culture you are using.

Comment: It is unlikely that this question will help any future visitiors since the code is not related to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

See this [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/Kepk1T) for the same code which compiles and executes just  fine.

```vb
Dim intDay As Integer
intDay = Date.Now.Day
Console.WriteLine(intDay)
```

The [`Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) property returns the current time as a DateTime value.
On which you can call the [`Day`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day.aspx) property which returns an integer

The error message you got refers to a string which is not in the posted code so I'm guessing the problem is somewhere else

Comment: You are correct.When I did the View in Browser and did a "SUBMIT", the error line was displaying on the "intDay=Date.Now.Day". The error was about 6 lines below the "intDate=...". What a surprise.

Comment: @Steve42: Don't use the browser as debugging tool. I asume that you are using Visual Studio. It has a builtin debugger that is very helpful to find such problems. At least it helps to identify the correct line.

Answer (score 1):

As Iam Asp.Net Developer I have Code Like This....

I Take Three Textboxes For Showing YYYY,MM,DD

```
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
    TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
    TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
```

This Gives Output Like This...

```
2013
08
08
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
    intDay = DateTime.Now.Day
```

Edit: didn't see the comment stating the in VB.NET Date is valid too ;)

Comment: -1 In VB.NET `Date` and `DateTime` both refer to the `System.DateTime` structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken straight from the docs.  So you should be able to assign DateTime.Now to moment and get what you want from it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day.aspx

```
Dim moment As New System.DateTime(1999, 1, 13, 3, 57, 32, 11)

' Year gets 1999. 
Dim year As Integer = moment.Year

' Month gets 1 (January). 
Dim month As Integer = moment.Month

' Day gets 13. 
Dim day As Integer = moment.Day

' Hour gets 3. 
Dim hour As Integer = moment.Hour

' Minute gets 57. 
Dim minute As Integer = moment.Minute

' Second gets 32. 
Dim second As Integer = moment.Second

' Millisecond gets 11. 
Dim millisecond As Integer = moment.Millisecond
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `DateTime.Now.Day`

Comment: -1 In VB.NET `Date` and `DateTime` both refer to the `System.DateTime` structure.