# VB.NET General function for "Now"

Tags: vb.net

I want to remove all dependencies to Microsoft.VisualBasic from my solution.

One thing that causes me problems is the "Now" function.

Does anybody know what would be a clean solution for a replacement?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you doing this? There are certain legacy holdovers to avoid from vb6, but other things in there are just part of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
Dim now As Date = Date.Now
```

It is a `Shared` property which means that you use it via classname without an instance.

Comment: As `Date` is an alias to `DateTime` in VB (refs: [Date instead of DateTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625795/date-instead-of-datetime), [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)) and the OP is apparently trying to avoid VB-specific things where possible, wasn't your original answer of `Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now` more in the spirit of what they want?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: he wants to avoid the `System.VisualBasic` namespace, he doesn't want to avoid VB.NET. I have always used `Date` instead of `DateTime` in VB.NET even if i have used Visual Basic  very rarely.

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought that maybe they wanted to go more directly to framework classes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: it _is_ a framework class since it's actually `System.DateTime`. It would be the same as if you'd say that you should use `System.Int32` in C# instead of `int` or `System.String` instead of `string`.

Comment: I find myself both agreeing and slightly disagreeing - maybe we can reasonably put it in the realm of "in-house styles" where both are in fact equally valid.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, you can use the `Now` property that is part of `System.DateTime`.